# ahk - Creating multiple key combos with return does not work

Tags: autohotkey

```
RAlt::
Hotkey, a, label_a, On
return

RAlt Up::
Hotkey, a, Off
return

label_a:
Send, 1
return
```

and this

```
RAlt & b::Send hello
```

These two ahk codes don't work together. However, by having only one of those two, the script works.

Is there a way to make them work together?

The reason for this is that I also have alt shift combos ctrl alt shift combos etc.

Comment: Your first code does not work for me. What do you want to do? Surely you can make multiple codes work together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**Custom Combinations**](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm#combo) says:

> For standard modifier keys, normal hotkeys typically work as well or
> better than "custom" combinations. For example, `<+s::` is recommended
> over `LShift & s::`.

You had better use

`>!b::` instead of `RAlt & b::`

`>!>+a::` in RAlt-RShift combos

`<!>+a::` in LAlt-RShift combos

etc.

See [**Hotkey Modifier Symbols**](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm#Symbols) in the documentation.